# Adding elements manually to a Cursor

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a `Cursor` which takes some categories from my DB, but I need to manually add a category which is not in the DB, so they can all be rendered in a `ListViewActivity`.
The way I get the categories is the following:

```
Cursor categories = myDbHelper.getCategoriesCursor(
                    categorySelected, Tools.getLanguage());
            startManagingCursor(categories);
            CategoriesCursorAdapter categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesCursorAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), categories);
            setListAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
```

I thought of creating a new `ArrayList<String>` with the fields I want and passing it to the `Adapter` but still, I can't grab those values and add them to the `categories` list.

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT: This is the method to  get the categories in 'my DatabaseHelper'

```
public Cursor getCategoriesCursor(int parentId, int language) {
        try {
        String sql = "";
        if (parentId == 0) {
            sql = "SELECT 0 as '_id', 'Agenda' as 'name_category', 0 as 'sort' UNION ALL SELECT categories._id, name_categories.name_category, categories.sort "
                    + "FROM categories JOIN name_categories ON categories._id = name_categories.category_id "
                    + "WHERE categories.parent_id = " + parentId
                    + " AND name_categories.language_id = " + language + " ORDER BY sort";
        } else {
            sql = "SELECT categories._id, name_categories.name_category "
                    + "FROM categories JOIN name_categories ON categories._id = name_categories.category_id "
                    + "WHERE categories.parent_id = "
                    + parentId
                    + " AND name_categories.language_id = " + language + " ORDER BY sort";
        }
        Log.d("XS2TheWorld", sql);
        return myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getCategoriesCursor(parentId, language);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be useful for us to see your `myDbHelper`.

Comment: probably MergeAdapter could provide clear solution for Your issue - checkout https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier: I just modified my SQL query and it worked